# Drag and Drop <object> tag, Data is missing in <object> tag in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I am dragging and dropping 3 div's(div tag). one div tag contain `object` tag in side `div` tag, in that object tag i'm displaying `PDF` file. when page loads `object` tag display's `PDF` file, after drag and drop `object` tag will not show pdf file, `object` tag is blank.

**HTML CODE**

```
       /* Display Box1*/
        <div class="parent">
         <div class="box child" id="child3">
         <div class="box-header">
         <h3 class="box-title">Information From Document Archive</h3>
         </div>
         <div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding" style="overflow: auto; padding-left: 5px; max-height: 250px;">
         <div style="z-index: -999;">
        <object data="file/DRAG.pdf" id="objpdf" class="col-sm-12">
         </object>
         </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
/* Display Box2 */
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6">
<div class="parent">
<div class="box child" id="child1">
<div class="box-header">
<h3 class="box-title">Information From AI Engine</h3>
<div class="box-tools">
<div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="width: 150px;">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding" style="overflow: auto; max-height: 300px;">
<table class="table table-hover">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th style="width: 200px;">Field</th>
<th>Value</th>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Permission Note</td>
 <td><span class="text-red">
 <asp:Label ID="lblPermissionNote" runat="server" Text="abcd"></asp:Label>
 </span></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Customer Comments</td>
 <td><span class="text-red">
 <asp:Label ID="lblCustomerComments" runat="server" Text="Test comments"></asp:Label>
</span></td>
</tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
  </div>

 <div class="col-sm-6">
 <div class="parent">
 <div class="box child" id="child2">
 <div class="box-header">
 <h3 class="box-title">Information From Mainframe Engine</h3>
<div class="box-tools">
<div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="width: 150px;">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding" style="overflow: auto; height: 300px;">
<table class="table table-hover">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>Field</th>
<th>Value</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Consignment Number</td>
<td><span class="text-black">
<asp:Label ID="lblMainFrameConsigmentNumber" runat="server" Text="1234556789"></asp:Label>
</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Account Number</td>
<td><span class="text-black">
<asp:Label ID="lblMainFrameTntAccountNumber" runat="server" Text="123456"></asp:Label>
</span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>                               
</div>
```

**JQuery Code**

```
$("document").ready(function () {
            $(".child").draggable({
                revert: true
            });
            $(".parent").droppable({
                accept: '.child',
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    if ($(this).children().length > 0) {
                        var move = $(this).children().detach();
                        $(ui.draggable).parent().append(move);
                    }

                    $(this).append($(ui.draggable));
                }
            });
        });
```

**CSS**

```
.parent {
         /*float: left;*/
         cursor: move;
         border: 2px dotted silver;
    }
```

### **Web Page Before Dragging**

[image: Web Page before dragging]

**Web Page after dragging**

[image]

Please suggest any solution.

Comment: Could you provide us with the markup from your site after drag and drop?

Comment: Hi. i've attached screenshots 'Before dragging' and 'After Dragging' in the question. please have a look.

Comment: I would need to see the code after dragging. The pictures I did see.

Comment: object tag code after dragging:-  <object class="col-sm-12" id="objpdf" data="file/DRAG.pdf"></object>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution. Instead of using `<object>` tag i used `<iframe>` tag. it worked for me.

**Before:**

```
<object data="file/DRAG.pdf" id="objpdf" class="col-sm-12">
         </object>
```

**Changed To:**

```
<iframe src="file/DRAG.pdf" class="col-sm-12" style="height:300px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```